# Unterminated JSX contents while trying to render content

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm learning ReactJs, so I don't have much idea about jsx. Can someone please help?

I tried closing the div in the other way round and checked for a typo. But I couldn't find any thing.

```
 //importing modules
 import React from 'react'
 import ReactDom from 'react-dom'

//create a component
const App=()=>{
    return <div> Hello sammy! <div/> ;
};

ReactDom.render(
    <App/> ,
    document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

I'm getting the following error[image: error]

Comment: typo: `<div/>`. voting to close as typo

Comment: Your closing div has a bad sintaxe. Just change `<div/>` to `</div>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  return <div> Hello sammy! <div/> ;
```

should be

```
  return <div> Hello sammy! </div> ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here as `<div/>`, which is not a correct closing tag.

```
<div> Hello sammy! <div/> ;
```

it should be `</div>`

```
<div> Hello sammy! </div> ;
```